# INSERT SQL y obtener ID (JEE)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, java-ee

Como dice el título, esto es en `java EE`, particularmente java web. Sin embargo, es una consulta `SQL` sencilla:

Tengo una tabla con varios datos, y un `id` autoincremental:

> id, fecha, texto.

Utilizo un servlet para agregar un elemento a la base de datos con la siguiente consulta:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (fecha, texto) VALUES (valor1, valor2)
```

Sin embargo, quiero obtener el `ID` que se generó. ¿Cual es la forma eficiente de hacerlo?

Se me ocurre generar otra consulta que obtenga el último elemento agregado, sin embargo, me parece ineficiente generar otra consulta. Además, si se agregan 2 elementos desde cuentas diferentes a tiempos parecidos, los códigos podrían cruzarse...
¿Alguna idea? ¿Saben si se puede obtener desde la misma consulta?

Answer (score 3):

Lo que quieres puedes obtenerlo usando la función de MySQL **LAST_INSERT_ID**, esta devuelve el último identificador insertado en la base de datos.
El identificador puedes obtenerlo añadiendo la siguiente consulta a la actual:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (fecha, texto) VALUES (valor1, valor2); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

De esta forma lo que consigues es que se ejecuten de forma simultánea ambas consultas y como resultado de su ejecución te devuelva el último dentificador insertado en la base de datos, en este caso el que se ha insertado usando la sentencia **INSERT**.

Puedes obtener más información acerca de esta función consultando la siguiente [página de la documentación de MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Answer (score 0):

> Se me ocurre generar otra consulta que obtenga el ultimo elemento
>   agregado, sin embargo, me parece ineficiente generar otra consulta.

No entiendo por qué ineficiente, si todo el tiempo los sistemas están haciendo consultas. Además, una consulta como esta toma realmente poquísimo tiempo.

```
SELECT id FROM Tabla ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Otra opción es crear un **procedimiento almacenado** que persista y devuelva los registros insertados incluidos el id autogenerado.

Por último, y la alternativa más fácil es usar JPA:

```
em.persist(producto);
em.flush();
return producto.getId();
```

En JPA cuando realizas un flush, la entidad persistida actualiza sus propiedades, entre ellas, el `ID` autogenerado, por lo que puedes hacer uso del getter solamente para obtenerlo.